# Access completed form fields in ServiceM8

Tags: json, api, rest

I am trying to access completed form field data in ServiceM8 including uploaded images. The api reference does not detail how to access them. Can anyone provide an example or documentation?

Comment: Just as an FYI, https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/Form.json - Will list all forms
https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/FormField.json - Will list form questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not publicly documented, but you can access completed forms via the FormResponses endpoint.

https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/FormResponse.json

```
[{
  "edit_date": "2015-02-17 11:12:22",
  "active": 1,
  "form_uuid": "578344cc-8d57-441b-a713-02207430f7cb",
  "staff_uuid": "",
  "regarding_object": "job",
  "regarding_object_uuid": "8b9bfe73-c43c-4275-bb4e-1aac9b6f8adb",
  "field_data": "removed (see below)",
  "timestamp": "2015-02-17 11:12:20",
  "form_by_staff_uuid": "0e72af0f-22db-4ddb-ac7d-eba2c1ef2d4b",
  "document_attachment_uuid": "6b73bfa3-3dd8-48b7-83b2-af1dcc78262b",
  "uuid": "ff1926c8-8879-41a5-9f2d-e4e4455e92eb"
}]
```

The actual responses to the questions are in the `field_data` property, which is itself a JSON-encoded string. Here's an example:

```
[
  {
    "UUID": "1ea64222-2b0e-4dc4-a99b-698603a9f59b",
    "FieldType": "Date",
    "Response": "Tue Feb 17 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0930 (ACST)",
    "SortOrder": 1,
    "Question": "Date"
  },
  {
    "UUID": "9b4ea087-d154-4fb7-831e-c17cb882157b",
    "FieldType": "Multiple Choice",
    "Response": "Blah",
    "SortOrder": 2,
    "Question": "Supplier"
  },
  {
    "UUID": "24fdd846-8fc8-4ddf-9d58-6c5fa1b5310b",
    "FieldType": "Text",
    "Response": "1",
    "SortOrder": 3,
    "Question": "Part 1 Qty"
  },
  {
    "UUID": "6162749f-5945-455c-95ca-ca31e9bd6a7b",
    "FieldType": "Text",
    "Response": "p1",
    "SortOrder": 4,
    "Question": "Item Part No. 1"
  },
  {
    "UUID": "fd5c8f67-c68d-4dcb-96a7-05341fbb3dab",
    "FieldType": "Text",
    "Response": "part one",
    "SortOrder": 5,
    "Question": "Item Name 1"
  },
  {
    "UUID": "6e591103-78d4-42a0-8657-5229b5b469fb",
    "FieldType": "Photo",
    "Response": "cf91bae2-b9da-42e2-87ee-b416109bb44b",
    "SortOrder": 14,
    "Question": "Take Photo of Items 1"
  },
  {
    "UUID": "c8719af5-b550-40cf-9d83-0ea67ab30e5b",
    "FieldType": "Signature",
    "Response": "90ac5b56-fc0e-4a3a-8935-f43cdd23c05b",
    "SortOrder": 17,
    "Question": "Signature"
  }
]
```

For photo questions (FieldType == Photo), the Response property contains a UUID which you can retrieve from the [Attachments endpoint](http://developer.servicem8.com/docs/rest-api/reference/attachment/).

JSON data for the attachment: `https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/Attachment/cf91bae2-b9da-42e2-87ee-b416109bb44b.json`

File data (i.e. the attachment itself): `https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/Attachment/cf91bae2-b9da-42e2-87ee-b416109bb44b.file`