# Edit submitted form field data in servicem8

Tags: forms

Once a form has been submitted there does not seem to be any way to edit the form data, am I missing something? If one of our field workers enters something in the form field that is offensive we have no way to edit the data. Does anyone have a way to edit the submitted form data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible via the UI, but you can edit form responses via the API. You need to use the FormResponse endpoint. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236584/access-completed-form-fields-in-servicem8/38237357#38237357) for more details.